# If I learn NHibernate will I know Hibernate? What about Spring.net and (Java) Spring?

Tags: hibernate, nhibernate, spring, spring.net

I am a core Java developer (J2SE) that was assigned to a one-man project, a small intranet website.

I was planning to learn Hibernate and Spring when my supervisor required Microsoft technologies. I decided to use ASP.Net MVC but I am feeling that I am missing a chance to learn what I wanted.

If I drop ASP.Net MVC and start learning NHibernate and Spring.Net will I be able to seamlessly transfer that knowledge to the Java environment?

**NOTE:** I once used iTextSharp, a .Net port from the popular Java iText (PDF library). The usage on both environments was 95% the same. Does this happen with Spring and Hibernate?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you learn NHibernate, you **know** Hibernate. If you learn Spring.net, you **know** Spring. It's the concepts which are important to understand, and if you have a strong grasp of those, you'll have no problem. The actual implementation details are something you can pick up rather quickly.

Comment: I disagree. It's the *detail* of Spring and Hibernate that are critical, not the concepts, which are in themselves fairly trivial.

Comment: But the implementation details are very similar between .NET and Java, so learning the two on the .NET side of things will enable you to transition almost seamlessly, more or less (but certainly for Hibernate), to Java.

Answer (score 4):

NHibernate and Hibernate are very similar and knowing one will get you 80% of the other. The Spring part? not so much.

I'm a .NET developer who uses NHibernate for everything, and three weeks ago, I had to do a web site using Oracle's (Sun?) Java Server Pages (JSP) for school. I previously had **zero** knowledge of Java whatsoever, and although it took me one or two days to learn the ropes of basic JSP pages, transferring my NHibernate knowledge to Java's Hibernate happened in an almost seamless fashion. In a week, I was able to hack a basic data-driven website in Java.

- I frequently use this Hibernate tutorial for my .NET applications: [Hibernate Reference Documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/reference/en/html/index.html)
- In a nutshell, to transfer my NHibernate knowledge to Java, the only guide I needed was Netbeans' simplistic "[Using Hibernate in a Web Application](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/web/hibernate-webapp.html)", as Hibernate's advanced features I already knew about.

Answer (score 1):

> If I drop ASP.Net MVC and start learning NHibernate and Spring.Net will I be able to seamlessly transfer that knowledge to the Java environment?

Unlikely. Hibernate and Spring are an order of magnitude more complex than something like iText. The .NET versions may have been inspired by the Java versions, but they're going to differ a lot in how they work. You'll likely be able to pick up the patterns and practices fairly quickly, but there's still going to be a steep learning curve if you want to do anything other than the most trivial of applications.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ASP.NET MVC **and** NHibernate **and** Spring.NET

Your supervisor will be happy, and you will be able to learn what you want to learn.